# GPO: Запретить вход (и регистрацию) в домен всех ПК (не серверов), кроме имен из нужного списка

Tags: windows

Есть AD домен в организации (мелкий, до 100 юзверей).
Как запретить ввод в домен ПК ниже определенной версии W10?

Ок. Определен список в GPO, кто может "УЗ АДМ" вводить в домен.
Теперь как запретить ввод в домен ПК, версия w10 ниже нужной (старая)?
Пробовал через Gpo\Wmi фильтры - но там явного запрета нет.
Есть список ПК, кому можно, остальных на..
Можно это как-то все все вместе срастить?
Чтобы если ПК из списка вводится - то отказ в регистрации в новом домене?

Comment: А чё у тебя там за такой проходной двор, что любой желающий вводит компы в домен?

Comment: Может пойти "тупым" способом - от обратного - периодически "выпиливать" не соответствующие требованиям компы с оповещением этого факта админа, формируя инцидент?